# How to connect icCube to mysql?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I just installed icCube and I would like to connect to a local mysql datasource and trying some reporting. I can't find explanations in the doc.
A starting point would be enough

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I went to the wrong entry point. http://localhost:8282/icCube/icCube.html

From there:

1. BUILDER
2. create schema
3. data sources: add